# ionic 2 throw errors module.js:471

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I worked on my project in ionic 2 and suddenly I tried to run

```
ionic serve
```

I got these errors

```
    module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\adirz\myapps\HaverSami\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: it looks like you didn't install something correctly ..try to delete all your node_modules folder and run again an npm install .. if it still not working ..check if you install ionic in the right way

Comment: I deleted all my folder, node and npm. when i try to check npm version I get errors

Comment: mmm looks very strange..so if you digit npm -v what it give to you?

Comment: something really strange, when i run ionic -v in some folder it works, in other it's shows the module.js:471 error

Comment: mmm you have to install ionic globally .. so try to do a npm install -g ionic (remeber if you want a specific version toput @verison) ..the important things is -g (globally) so you can run from vevery where ionic command

Comment: that's exactly how i do..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132292/discussion-between-federico-scamuzzi-and-adir-zoari).

Answer (score 0):

Open **CMD (CLI) as administrator** and type `npm install -g ionic@latest`. After that, try `ionic serve` again.